# Authlogic: How to block certain names and email addresses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, registration

Using Authlogic, what's the proper way to ban certain usernames and domains (for email addresses)? The list if usernames and domains to block would be updated on an ongoing basis.

For instance, I don't want anyone to register with the username "admin" or "moderator" and I there are a slew of domain names I'd want to block from registering (for spam purposes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Active Record [validates_exclusion_of](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M000089).

```
class User
  validates_exclusion_of :username, :in => %w( admin moderator )
end
```

Comment: What about domains in email addresses?

Comment: Use a different validator like `validates_format_of` or write your own validator. The ActiveRecord 3 API is very flexible because let you create validators as objects.